# PHP - Cookies, como detectar se está criado

Tags: php, cookies

Como faço para detectar se um cookie existe ?

Meu cookie é criado assim:

```
setcookie("log", "true", time()+60, "/classes");
```

E para detectar estou tentando isso:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['log'])) {
   //função
}
```

Mas ele não detecta o cookie, ele roda a função dentro do if mesmo se o cookie existir..

Segue os dados do cookie no chrome:

```
Nome:   log
Conteúdo:   true
Caminho:    /classes
Enviar para:    Qualquer tipo de conexão
Acessível ao script:    Sim
Criado em:  segunda-feira, 12 de setembro de 2016 14:05:10
```

Comment: Primeiro você esta verificando se **não existe**! Tão logo se não existir vai executar a função. Segundo se você definiu u "path" para o cookie deve verificá-lo neste "path".

Comment: como verifico no "path" `/classes` ?

Comment: Por exemplo: se você esta trabalhando em localhost seria isto: "localhost/classes" o path é o diretório dentro de seu dominio... pelo menos foi isso que você definiu quando mandou o cookie ser salvo em "/classes"

Comment: @LauroMoraes, seria algo assim `$_COOKIE['localhost/classes/log']` ?

Comment: Não. Você pegua o cookie pelo nome que definiu ex: $_COOKIE['log']. Note que: quando você salvou o cookie você "disse" para ele que ele pertence ao diretório "seudominio.com/classes" se você realmente tiver este diretótrio em seu projeto/site blz basta acessar "seudominio.com/classes" e na index deste diretório verificar se o cookie existe. Caso não tenha este diretório, então salve o cookie em "/"

Comment: Você tem um subdiretório chamado "classes" ?

Comment: tenho! salvei o cookie em "/" e funcionou, vlw!

Comment: Só pra complementar, material essencial de leitura: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 1):

Bom você esta fazendo uma validação se **NÃO EXISTE**  o seus Cookie, sendo assim, sua função será executada apenas se o cookie não for criado, lembrando que "!" na validação faz o inverso do cogido "isset". E veja se realmente exite o diretório /classes em seu projeto onde você salvou este cookie.
Espero ter ajudado e boa sorte!

Answer (score -2):

Não está claro onde está invocando o `isset()`. Portanto a resposta pressupõe que esteja na mesma página onde invocou `setcookie()`.

Nesse caso não será acessível a menos que declare explicitamente na variável global `$_COOKIE`.

```
setcookie("log", "true", time()+60, "/classes");
var_dump($_COOKIE); // Não retorna o índice "log", registrado acima em `setcookie()`
```

Isso acontece porque a variável global `$_COOKIE` com o índice "log" só estará disponível na próxima requisição.

Para torná-lo disponível na mesma página onde é criado, deve setar explicitamente assim:

```
setcookie('log', true, time()+60, '/classes');
$_COOKIE['log'] = true;
```

<sub>Nota: esse comportamento varia conforme o browser e sua respectiva versão. Por via das dúvidas, sempre sete explicitamente a variável global.</sub>

Para tornar mais prático e reutilizável, crie uma rotina:

```
function CookieSet($k, $v) {
    setcookie($k, $v, time()+60, '/classes');
    $_COOKIE[$k] = $v;
}

CookieSet('log', true);
```

Obviamente, verifique se o quarto parâmetro de `setcookie()` está correto

Está definindo como `'/classes'`. Talvez queira usar `'/'`.

Definindo como `'/classes'`, estará limitando os cookies ao diretório `'/classes'`. ex: `http://localhost/classes`. Se acessar `http://localhost/`, não estarão disponíveis.